# Can't populate an array with data from Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below I try to make an array ChatListings, but it doesn't work.

```
let chatRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chatListings")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let firstQuery = chatRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: userID)
    firstQuery.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            print("child is \(child)")
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                print("dict is \(dict)")
                let roomKey = dict["chatRoomKey"] as! String
                let oUID = dict["otherUserID"] as! String
                let oUserName = dict["otherUserName"] as! String
                let oProfilePic = dict["otherUserProfilePic"] as! String
                let userIDTemp = dict["userID"] as! String
                chatListing = ChatListing(chatRoomKey: roomKey, UID: userIDTemp, name: oUserName, otherUserID: oUID, otherUserProfilePicURL: oProfilePic)
                chatListings.append(chatListing)
            }
        }
        print("chatListings = \(chatListings)")
    })
}
```

This crashes saying that the compiler unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I don't know why it won't work. I've tried every which way I can find to extract the data that the compiler reads moments before crashing or failing to fill an array of my 'chatlisting' objects.

Here's an example of the data that the compiler reads but cannot extract with maybe 4 different coding attempts:

```
"-KjdSF97Q2z3afXzkwQ9": {
chatRoomKey = "-KjdSF97Q2z3afXzkwQ9";
messages =     {
    "-KjdSOVTsg8jEy6SeEA2" =         {
        MediaType = PHOTO;
        fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/preollify.appspot.com/o/mget8KN2nHe4sOhbnWTixYvCOrr2%2F515963239.371526?alt=media&token=6cb12ec1-5bdb-43a1-ab49-90c90570b341";
        senderId = mget8KN2nHe4sOhbnWTixYvCOrr2;
        senderName = Michael;
    };
    "-KjdSPxpNT0pkQ1y5-_1" =         {
        MediaType = VIDEO;
        fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/preollify.appspot.com/o/mget8KN2nHe4sOhbnWTixYvCOrr2%2F515963229.282051?alt=media&token=04671c8e-d7f1-49f2-81d0-09836c034ae2";
        senderId = mget8KN2nHe4sOhbnWTixYvCOrr2;
        senderName = Michael;
    };
    "-KjdVaVTfbaC-3S-91-A" =         {
        MediaType = TEXT;
        senderId = mget8KN2nHe4sOhbnWTixYvCOrr2;
        senderName = Michael;
        text = The;
    };
};
otherUserID = aRandomUser3611;
otherUserName = Michael;
otherUserProfilePic = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/preollify.appspot.com/o/ProfilePictures%2Fmget8KN2nHe4sOhbnWTixYvCOrr2%2FmediumProfilePicture.jpg?alt=media&token=d88afa5d-0db7-4ce2-95c9-3038ff592e9f";
userID = mget8KN2nHe4sOhbnWTixYvCOrr2;
```

I'm trying to extract all the data but the messages part, which I plan on doing later in the app.

This data (excluding the "messages" part) gets written in the chatViewController's viewDidLoad like this:

```
    let preMessageRef = chatRef.childByAutoId()
    chatListingID = preMessageRef.key
    let initialChatRoomData = ["chatRoomKey": chatListingID, "otherUserID": otherUID, "otherUserName": otherUserName, "otherUserProfilePic": otherUserProfilePicURLString, "userID": userID]
    preMessageRef.setValue(initialChatRoomData)
```

Retrieving data from Firebase Database has been completely hit or miss for me, with copying the successful attempts of extracting data rarely working twice. Their documentation is minimal to the point of leaving out way too much as it provides little help for how to extract data in real world contexts. Why do people like Firebase? It has been a very frustrating experience working with Firebase and I definitely regret it. But it's probably too late to turn back and go with something better, i.e. a platform that provides clear instruction for how to get it to work.

Comment: In `init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot)`, what is happening really? Since there are a lot of return nil, one of it could cause the issue. What works, what doesn't?

Comment: Crash? How, that's totally a different case! Show the error message and the value.

Comment: Can you post the crash message? You are force unwrapping all your values as `String`s, are you certain they are actually all `String` objects? In the data you posted `otherUserID = aRandomUser3611` and `otherUserName = Michael` do not look like `String` objects.

Comment: If they're not String objects, what else could they be?

Comment: Those values that show it being written to Firebase Database are all strings. But I see how some are in quotes while others are not. I don't know why that happens or what it means.

Comment: I believe Firebase uses `json` values, so they could be `int`, `bool`, `float` or even `object` types. How are the values defined in Firebase?. Try putting a breakpoint at the line `print("dict is \(dict)")` and then step through each line to see which line actually crashes.

Comment: Tried that. This line crashes:

Comment: let roomKey = dict["chatRoomKey"] as! String

Comment: I don't think I've gotten it successfully extract any of the values, not just specific ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a silly typo. Try this:

```
let childData = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
print("child key: \(childData.key)")
if let dict = childData.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    ...
}
```

that is, use `child` instead of `snapshot`.

---

**Update**. Turns out using `NSDictionary`, rather than `Dictionary`, fixed the `dict` constant crashes. But, besides compiler bugs, still not clear why...

Comment: The compiler responds first with a fix it error, making it read like this once accepted:

Comment: if let dict = (child as AnyObject).value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Comment: Then it says it's an ambiguous use of .value. So I wish that change would fix it, but it doesn't appear to.

Comment: I tried it, but it crashed without explanation on the line right below it. When I comment out that line and try it again, it crashes on the line below that. Couldn't tell you why.

Comment: The print outputs the correct childByAutoID value, which is one of the values that I want extracted. With your changes it still crashes anywhere where "dict" tries to extract a value or even when it's just going to be printed. Again, no explanation from the compiler.

Comment: When I tried that, it crashed on that print statement.

Comment: All I had to do was change declaring dict as NSDictionary rather than Dictionary. Works!

Comment: Glad to hear ;) But still very weird... both forms should work fine. Maybe it's a bug in the Swift compiler, I don't know...